# TypeError: fs.stat is not a function (IPFS JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs, js-ipfs

I'm learning ipfs js based on the tutorial, but while I'm following I'm having trouble typing node main.js in the terminal like this:

```
/Users/username/Documents/coding/ipfs-test/node_modules/lock-me/src/unix.js:9
    (cb) => fs.stat(name, (err, stats) => {
               ^

TypeError: fs.stat is not a function
    at waterfall (/Users/username/Documents/coding/ipfs-test/node_modules/lock-me/src/unix.js:9:16)
    at nextTask (/Users/username/Documents/coding/ipfs-test/node_modules/async/waterfall.js:16:14)
    at exports.default (/Users/username/Documents/coding/ipfs-test/node_modules/async/waterfall.js:26:5)
    at unixLock (/Users/username/Documents/coding/ipfs-test/node_modules/lock-me/src/unix.js:8:3)
    at lock (/Users/username/Documents/coding/ipfs-test/node_modules/lock-me/src/index.js:53:5)
    at Object.exports.lock (/Users/username/Documents/coding/ipfs-test/node_modules/ipfs-repo/src/lock.js:23:3)
    at IpfsRepo._openLock (/Users/username/Documents/coding/ipfs-test/node_modules/ipfs-repo/src/index.js:168:18)
    at waterfall (/Users/username/Documents/coding/ipfs-test/node_modules/ipfs-repo/src/index.js:96:20)
```

This is code written in main.js:

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs');
console.log("Imported IPFS");
const mynode = new IPFS();
console.log("Starting Server");

mynode.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log("Server Started");
    const version = await mynode.version();
    console.log(version.version);
});
```

Information:
I'm using node js version 8.13.0,
The IPFS JS I'm using is version 0.32.3,
With OS MacOS Bigsur 11.4

Is there a solution to this problem? Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what tutorial you're following, but here's a minimal example of getting your code to run using js-ipfs 0.55.3:

```js
const IPFS = require('ipfs');
console.log("Imported IPFS");

async function run() {
    console.log("Starting Server");
    const mynode = await IPFS.create();

    console.log("Server Started");
    const version = await mynode.version();
    console.log(version.version);
}

run();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, the method you gave really worked perfectly if it was run with the latest node js with ipfs js version 0.55.3.

However, for Node js version 8.13.0, and IPFS JS version 0.32.3 it doesn't work.

An error like this appears:

`Imported IPFS
Starting Server
(node:25730) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: IPFS.create is not a function`

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @AdamFaturahman is there any way you can avoid using such an old version of js-ipfs? It's difficult to support much older versions of software (especially before 1.0), I usually recommend people use the latest version of js-ipfs wherever possible. Please let me know if it's impossible though, and why :).